# Tab navigation in bootstrap not working with another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in dilemna on how to get this resolved. Basically I am using tab in bootstrap modal and is using button to navigate from one tab to another. I incorporatyed jquery for that. But I also wrote a jquery to allow me to select multiple radio button with same name (using value), But when I incorprated jquery library it seems to stop navigation from happening and when I remove this jquery navigation strrats happening. I believe this happening because jquery for radio button is v1.3.2 while for navigation is v2.1.1 . however I need to use both to fulfil the requirement? please suggest on how to resolve this. Below is the code :

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#selectINTI").click(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=app_decision]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
            //$('input:radio[name=app_decision]')[0].checked = true;
            });
            $("#selectINTE").click(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=app_decision]:nth(1)').attr('checked',true);
            //$('input:radio[name=app_decision]')[1].checked = true;
            });
            $("#selectR").click(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=app_decision]:nth(2)').attr('checked',true);
            //$('input:radio[name=app_decision]')[2].checked = true;
            });
          }); 
 
 $('.btnNext').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
fieldset {
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:10px;
padding:20px;
position:relative;
}
legend {
background: #FF9;
border: solid 1px black;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
padding: 4px;
margin:0px;
}
    .modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 90%;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>admission_dec</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--This is Jquery to select the multiple radio button on click of button-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
        <body>
        <fieldset>
        <legend><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Search</legend>
        <div class="row">
        <div class ="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="acad_period">Academic Year</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="form-control input-sm"  name="acad_period" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="stuclass">Class</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="stuclass" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Please select...</option>
        <option value="13">XII</option>
        <option value="12">XI</option>
        <option value="11">X</option>
        <option value="10">IX</option>
        <option value="9">VIII</option>
        <option value="8">VII</option>
        <option value="7">VI</option>
        <option value="6">V</option>
        <option value="5">IV</option>
        <option value="4">III</option>
        <option value="3">II</option>
        <option value="2">I</option>
        <option value="1">KG/Prep</option>
        <option value="Nurs">Nursery</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="appstatus">Application Status</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="appstatus" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Please select...</option>
        <option value="N">New</option>
        <option value="INTI">Invited for Interview</option>
        <option value="INTE">Invited for Exam</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="margin-left: 875px;">
        <input name="adm_search" value="Search" class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> 
        <input name="adm_cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">
        <br>
        </div>
        </fieldset>


        <br>
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table-hover">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="5" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top; width: 142x; text-align: left;"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Result</th>
        <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 323px; text-align: center;">Decision</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 120px; text-align: center;">Student ID</th>
        <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 250px; text-align: center;">Name</th>
        <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 65px; text-align: center;">App.Status</th>
        <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 65px; text-align: center;">App.Date</th>
        <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 350px;">
        <button name="app_intall"  class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Interview All" id="selectINTI"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Interview All</button>
        <button name="app_eall" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Exam All" id="selectINTE"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Exam All</button>
        <button name="app_rall" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Reject All" id="selectR"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Reject All</button>
        </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 79px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View</button>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 149px;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 250px;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 145px;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 140px;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width:120px; text-align: center;">
        <input name="app_decision" value="INTI" type="radio" >Interview

        <input name="app_decision" value="INTE" type="radio">Exam

        <input name="app_decision" value="R" type="radio">Reject
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="margin-left: 875px;">
        <button type="button" name="adm_submit"  class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Process</button>
        <button type="reset" name="adm_cancel"  class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
        </div>

        <!-- The Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Student Appilcation Form</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div role="tabpanel">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="appdetailTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Applicant Detail</a>

                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="adddetailTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Additional Details</a>

                        </li>

                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#fdetailTab" aria-controls="fdetailTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Father's Detail</a>

                        </li>

                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#mdetailTab" aria-controls="mdetailTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mother's Detail</a>

                        </li>

                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#gdetailTab" aria-controls="gdetailTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Guardian's Detail</a>

                        </li>

                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#sdetailTab" aria-controls="sdetailTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sibling's Detail</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <br>
                        <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        <div class ="form-inline">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="file:///C:/Users/Gaurav/Pictures/Saved%20Pictures/test%20photo.jpg" alt="Student image" style="border: 2px solid ; width: 165px; height: 214px;" align="right" hspace="5" vspace="1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="stutitle">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="stutitle" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="stugender">Gender</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="stugender" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="stuage">Age(yrs)</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="stuage" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stufname">Firstname</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="stufname" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stuheight">Height(cm)</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="stuheight" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stmdob">Birthdate</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="studob" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stsname">Surname</label>
        <input name="stusname" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stumobile">Mobile</label>
        <input name="stumobile" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stuhphone">Homephone</label>
        <input name="stuhphone" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stunatn">Nationality</label>
        <input name="stunatn" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stsname">Middlename</label>
        <input name="stumname" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br>
        <label for="stuemail">Email Address</label>
        <input size="52" class="form-control input-sm" name="stuemail" readonly>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <br>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Address Details</legend>
        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="stuadd1">Address Line 1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="stuadd1" size="40" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="stuadd2">Address Line 2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="stuadd2" size="40"  class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <br><br>
        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="stuadd3">Address Line 3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="stuadd3" size="40"  class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="stucity">City</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="stucity" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="stustate">State</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stustate" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="stucountry">Country</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="stucountry" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="stupostcode">Pincode</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="stupostcode" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <br>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Application Details</legend>
        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="appclass_applied" >Class Applied for</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="appclass_applied" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="acad_period" >Year Applied for</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input  name="acad_period" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="app_prevclass">Previous Class</label>
        <input  name="app_prevclass"  size="5" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Year Passed</label>
        <input  name="app_prevyear"  size="5" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="app_prevcgpaper">Previous CGPA/Percentage</label>
        <input name="app_prevcgpaper"  size="5" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label for="app_prevschlname">Previous School Name</label>
        <input name="app_prevschlname" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
        <label>Previous School Board</label>
        <input name="app_prevboard" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        <input name="app_prevboard_oth" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <br>
        <p class="tabnav" align="right">
                 <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next >> </a>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </p>
                </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">


        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label for="stublgrp">Blood Group</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stublgrp" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label for="stuweight">Weight(kg)</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stuweight" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <br>
        <label>Student Category</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stucategory" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        <input name="stucato" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label>Allergy ?</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stuallergy_yes" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label>Disability ?</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="studisability_yes" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label>Transport needed ?</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stutransport" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label>School Distance (km)</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stutransport_dist" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <br>
        <label for="stubplace">Birth Place</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stubplace" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <br>
        <label for="stumthtng">Mother Tongue</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stumthtng" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <br>
        <label for="stureligion">Religion</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stureligion" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label for="stuidentity">Identity Type</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stuidentity" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <label for="stuidentitynum">Id Number</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="stuidentitynum" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
        <br>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p class="tabnav" align="right">
        <br>        
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><< Previous</a>
        <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next >> </a>         
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </p>
        </div>
        </div>      
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="fdetailTab">
        <p class="tabnav" align="right">
        <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next >> </a> 
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><< Previous</a>  
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="mdetailTab">
        <p class="tabnav" align="right">                                
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><< Previous</a>  
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </p>

        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="gdetailTab">
        77777777
        <p class="tabnav" align="right">        
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><< Previous</a>  
        <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next >> </a> 
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </p>
        </div>



        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="sdetailTab">
        <br>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table-hover">
        <tbody>

        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birthdate</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Gende</th>
        <th>School Name</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
        </table>
        <p class="tabnav" align="right">                                
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><< Previous</a>  
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </p>                
        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>


        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely, loading only the higher version and ignoring the lower one will make both work. What you want is possible, but it's really the wrong way to go about it and would be like taking the helicopter to go buy some bread from the corner.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't include jQuery more than once, if you do there is a .noConflict() function (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) you could use. Doesn't seem like you need the two versions of jQuery though.

Comment: @eric  if I only incorporate one then the other doesnt work So I have to include both of them. I tored noconflict but want that helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that attr wasn't properly unsetting the checked property. If you remove your old jQuery library (v1.3.2) you can use the .prop function which handles the toggles correctly (http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#selectINTI").click(function() {
     $('input:radio[name=app_decision]:nth(0)').prop('checked', true);
   });
   $("#selectINTE").click(function() {
     $('input:radio[name=app_decision]:nth(1)').prop('checked', true);
   });
   $("#selectR").click(function() {
     $('input:radio[name=app_decision]:nth(2)').prop('checked', true);
   });
});
```